# Using java.net.URLConnection to fetch data in html fetching only html code and not the actual data

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

Using java.net.URLConnection to fetch data from html is not fetching the actual data but only the html code.
Since the html is generating data dynamically the core html code doesn't have the data that is being displayed on the html.

Is there any other means of fetching the data being displayed on the html page?

My code goes like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class Example {

         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
             System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
                   // Make a URL to the web page
                    URL url = new URL("https://rci-dtengine.rnd.ki.sw.ericsson.se/root//proj/cpptemp/jcat-cpp/DI/megatron/DT/INT_PA284/20170331_152720/20170331_152723/index.html");

                    // Get the input stream through URL Connection
                    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

                    // Once you have the Input Stream, it's just plain old Java IO stuff.

                    // For this case, since you are interested in getting plain-text web page
                    // I'll use a reader and output the text content to System.out.

                    // For binary content, it's better to directly read the bytes from stream and write
                    // to the target file.


                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    String line = null;

                    // read each line and write to System.out
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }

        }
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/jcat_m3.png"/>
<title>JCAT Test Report</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/top.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/testsuite.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.storage.js"></script>
<script src="js/stupidtable.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/top.js"></script>
<script src="js/testsuite.js"></script>

<script>
window.onerror = function () {
    alert("Failed to load data files as the format is corrupt!");
};
function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.data !== "reload from settings") {
        return;
    }
    window.location.reload();
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
<script src="json/suite.data.js"></script>
<script src="json/top.data.js"></script>
<script src="json/bulletin.message.data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='top'></div>
    <div id="bulletin">
        <div id="bulletinBar">
            <img id="bulletinSwitch"></img>
            <span id="bulletinHint" style="display:none">hide bulletin</span>
        </div>
        <div id="bulletinFrame" class="ui-widget-content">
            <div id="bulletinContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="autoRefresh">
        <span id="refreshCountDown" style="display:none"></span>
        <input id='autoRefreshBtn' type='button' value='enable auto refresh'></input>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="sumBlock">
            <h3>Report Summary</h3>
            <table id="suiteInfo" summary="Suite summary information">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="130px">Suite name:</td>
                        <td id="suiteName"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Run by:</td>
                        <td id="runBy"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time started:</td>
                        <td id="startTime" class="timestamp"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time finished:</td>
                        <td id="endTime" class="timestamp"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Duration:</td>
                        <td id="duration"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="staBlock">
            <h3>Statistics</h3>
            <table id="statistics" summary="Suite statistic">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100px">Passed TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcPassed" width="50px"></td>
                        <td width="120px">Passed configs:</td>
                        <td id="configTcPassed" width="50px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Failed TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcFailed"></td>
                        <td >Failed configs:</td>
                        <td id="configTcFailed"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Error TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcError"></td>
                        <td>Error configs:</td>
                        <td id="configTcError"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Skipped TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcSkipped"></td>
                        <td>Skipped configs:</td>
                        <td id="configTcSkipped"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Excluded TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcExcluded"></td>
                        <td>Executed configs:</td>
                        <td id="configTcRun"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Inconclusive TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcInconclusive"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Executed TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcRun"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>UnExecuted TCs:</td>
                        <td id="tcNotRun"></td>
                        <td>TCs & configs:</td>
                        <td id="tcTotalRun"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="testCases">
            <input placeholder="Search..." type="text" id="filterText" maxlength="200" style="margin-left:5px;"/>
            <div id='viewSwitch' style='display:none'>
                | <span id="nestedFunc" style='display:none'> Show Nested Suites<input  id='nestedSwitch' onchange="switchSuiteTable(this)" type="checkbox" value="Nested"></span>
                <span id="groupedFunc" style='display:none'> Show Grouped Suite<input  id='groupedSwitch' onchange="switchSuiteTable(this)" type="checkbox" value="Grouped"></span>
                Auto-unfold Errors<input  id='autoUnfold' onchange="setAutoUnfold()" type="checkbox" value="autoUnfold" checked="checked">
                <input id="unfoldFunc" type="button" value="Unfold" onclick="$('tr.folded').click()">
                <input id="foldFunc" type="button" value="Fold" onclick="$('tr.unfolded').click()">
            </div>
            | <span id="filter_icondown" style="color: #99cc00">&#9658</span> <span id="filter_iconright" style="color: #99cc00; display: none">&#9660</span>
            <a id="filterHide" href="javascript:hideUnhideTable('filter')">Filters</a>
            <div id="jcat_label">
                | <span id="label_text">Labels:</span>
                <select id="label_select">
                </select>
            </div>
            <table id="filter" style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="120px">Passed TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td width="50px"><a id="label_passed" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('passed')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td width="160px">Skipped TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td width="50px"><a id="label_skipped" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('skipped')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td width="160px">All testcases:</td>
                    <td width="50px"><a id="label_testcases" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('testcases')">Hide</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Failed TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_failed" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('failed')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td>Excluded TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_excluded" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('excluded')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td>All configuration methods:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_cfgs" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('cfgs')">Hide</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Error TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_error" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('error')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td>Inconclusive TCs/configs:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_inconc" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('inconc')">Hide</a></td>
                    <td>All reruned testcases:</td>
                    <td><a id="label_rerun" href="javascript:hideUnhideRows('rerun')">Show</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="suiteTable" class='suite'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sort="int" id="tcIndex" style="display:none">Index</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">ID</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Name</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Type</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Heading</th>
                        <th data-sort="int">State</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Additional Result Info</th>
                        <th data-sort="string" style="display:none;">Start Time</th>
                        <th data-sort="string" style="display:none;">End Time</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Duration</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Fetched Logs</th>
                        <th data-sort="string">Labels</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <table id="nestedTable" class='suite Nested' style="display:none">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="tcIndex" style="display:none">Index</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Heading</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Additional Result Info</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">Start Time</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">End Time</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Fetched Logs</th>
                        <th>Labels</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            <table id="groupedTable" class='suite Grouped' style="display:none">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="tcIndex" style="display:none">Index</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Heading</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Additional Result Info</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">Start Time</th>
                        <th style="display:none;">End Time</th>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <th>Fetched Logs</th>
                        <th>Labels</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the type of the actual data you’re expecting?  (I would check myself, but that URL’s server appears to be nonexistent.)

Comment: @VGR That URL server can not be accessed by public actually. Anyway, the actual data I wanna fetch is the data being displayed in the browser. And not the html code data.
It seems that the html code is generating the data through json objects. So I need to fetch the data which is displayed and not the code.

Comment: Are you asking how to directly access the JSON API from which the data was obtained, or you asking how to “scrape” the page to extract the data from the HTML?

Comment: Both will do @VGR. Either the JSON object or the scraping of the page will fetch me the data required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know the underlying API is if the site itself makes that information public.

As for loading the page, you’ll need a container capable of loading the page and executing its JavaScript;  the [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) class of JavaFX is one such container.  Every WebView has an associated WebEngine which provides the loaded page as an XML [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getDocument--) (even if the original content was not XHTML);  you can use [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newXPath--) on that Document to extract the text of the relevant `<td>` elements.